# Problema con función Buscar en tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite3

Estoy haciendo una base de datos utilizando python y de galería tkinter, este código tiene que permitir almacenar varios registros dentro de la base de datos, pero tengo un problema con la función buscar, en ella se debe buscar el código dentro de un treeview usando SQL, pero tengo este error: "TypeError: argument 1 must be str, not tuple" he intentado solucionarlo pero no lo he logrado, adjunto el código:

```
from sqlite3.dbapi2 import Cursor 
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import *

import tkinter.messagebox as mb
import sqlite3

class Product: 

 db_name = "kardex.db"

 def __init__(self,window):   
     self.wind = window
     self.wind.title('Kardex')
     window.geometry("784x480")

     my_menu = Menu(self.wind)
     self.wind.config(menu=my_menu)
     
     my_menu.add_command(label="Salir del registro", command = self.exit)
 
     frame = LabelFrame(self.wind, text = '\t \t \t \t   Registro      de\tInsumos',fg 'navy',font=("Calibri", 12))
     frame.grid(row = 0, column = 4, columnspan = 3, pady = 7, padx= 15)

     Label(frame, text = 'Código', fg = 'black').grid(row = 1, column = 0, pady = 1)
     self.name = Entry(frame)
     self.name.focus()
     self.name.grid(row = 2, column = 0)

     Label(frame, text = "Descripción", fg = 'black').grid(row = 1, column = 1)
     self.name1 = Entry(frame)
     self.name1.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
     
     Label(frame, text = 'UND', fg = 'black').grid(row = 1, column = 2)
     self.name2 = Entry(frame)
     self.name2.grid(row = 2, column = 2)
     
     Label(frame, text = 'St.Bodega', fg = 'black').grid(row = 1, column = 3)
     self.price = Entry(frame)
     self.price.grid(row = 2, column = 3)

     Label(frame, text = 'Cantidad.adq', fg = 'black').grid(row = 1, column = 4)
     self.price1 = Entry(frame)
     self.price1.grid(row = 2, column = 4)
     
     Label(frame, text = "Costo", fg = 'black').grid(row = 1, column = 5 )
     self.price2 = Entry(frame)
     self.price2.grid(row = 2, column = 5)

     ttk.Button(frame, text = 'Guardar datos', command=self.add_product).grid(row = 3, columnspan = 6, sticky = W + E)

     Label(frame, text = 'Buscar registro:',font=("Calibri", 11) ).grid(row = 8, column = 1)
     self.look = Entry(frame)
     self.look.grid(row = 8, column = 2)

     ttk.Button(frame, text = 'Buscar datos', command = self.search).grid(row = 8, column=3, columnspan=1, padx=8, sticky = W + E)
     self.btn_search = ttk.Button(frame, text="Restablecer datos", command = self.reset)
     self.btn_search.grid(row = 8, column = 4,sticky = W + E)

     self.message = Label(frame, text = '', fg = 'red')
     self.message.grid(row = 5, column = 3, columnspan = 2, sticky= W +E) 

     self.tree = ttk.Treeview(frame, height= 12, columns = 4)
     vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(orient="vertical",command=self.tree.yview)
     vsb.place(x=767, y=158, height=242+25)
     self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
     self.tree.grid(row = 6, column = 0, columnspan = 7, pady= 15)
     self.tree['column'] = ('#0', '#1', '#2', '#3', '#4') 
     self.tree.heading('#0', text = 'Código')
     self.tree.column ('#0',width = 100) 
     self.tree.heading('#1', text = 'Descripción')
     self.tree.column ('#1',width = 252)
     self.tree.heading('#2', text = 'UND' )
     self.tree.column ('#2',width = 95)
     self.tree.heading('#3', text = 'St.Bodega')
     self.tree.column ('#3',width = 100)
     self.tree.heading('#4', text = 'Cantidad.adq')
     self.tree.column ('#4',width = 100)
     self.tree.heading('#5', text = 'Costo')
     self.tree.column ('#5',width = 100)

 #llenar filas
     self.get_products()

 def run_query(self, query, parameters = ()): 
     with sqlite3.connect(self.db_name) as conn : 
         cursor = conn.cursor()
         result = cursor.execute(query, parameters)
         conn.commit()
     return result
 
 def get_products(self):  
     records = self.tree.get_children()
     for element in records:
         self.tree.delete(element)
     query = 'SELECT * FROM codigo ORDER BY ID DESC' 
     db_rows = self.run_query(query) 
     for row in db_rows:
         self.tree.insert('', 0, text = (row[1]), values = (row [2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6]))
 
 def validation(self):
  try:   
      return str(self.name.get()), (self.name1.get()), str(self.name2.get()), int(self.price.get()), int(self.price1.get()) and float(self.price2.get())
  except ValueError:
      mb.showerror('Los datos no se han podido registrar','Los datos no han sido ingresados o han sido ingresados incorrectamente', icon = 'error')

 def add_product(self):
     if self.validation() : 
        query = 'INSERT INTO codigo VALUES(NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'
        parameters =  (self.name.get(), self.name1.get(), self.name2.get(), self.price.get(), self.price1.get(), self.price2.get()) 
        self.run_query(query, parameters)
        self.message['text'] = 'Producto {} añadido exitosamente'. format(self.name1.get())
        self.name.delete  (0,END)
        self.name1.delete (0,END)
        self.name2.delete (0,END)
        self.price.delete (0,END)
        self.price1.delete(0,END)
        self.price2.delete(0,END)
     else:
        self.message['text'] = 'Ingrese los datos/ingreselos correctamente'
     self.get_products()

 def reset(self):
     self.get_products()

 def search(self): 
     
    self.lookup_records = self.look.get() 
    query=' SELECT * FROM codigo WHERE Código LIKE "?" ', (self.lookup_records,)
    parameters = (len(self.lookup_records)>0)
    self.run_query(query, parameters)
    self.message['text'] = 'Registro encontrado ' 
    self.get_products()
     
 def exit(self):
    MsgBox = mb.askquestion('Salir de la aplicación', '¿Está seguro de que desea salir del registro?', icon='warning')
    if MsgBox == 'yes':
        window.destroy()
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
     window = Tk()
     window.resizable(0,0)
     application = Product(window)
window.mainloop()
```

La conexión con la ase de datos esta almacenada dentro de dos funciones, en ella se debe de ingresar el "query" y los "parameters" que deben tener

Answer (score 0):

Prueba este código, ya realice algunas búsquedas y quedo bien. Ojala que ayude. Saludos.

```py
from sqlite3.dbapi2 import Cursor 
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import *

import tkinter.messagebox as mb
import sqlite3

try:

    db_name = "kardex.db"
    connection_db=sqlite3.connect(db_name) # INICIAR LA CONEXIÓN A LA DB
    tables_connection_db=connection_db.cursor() 

    #CREAR TABLA
    tables_connection_db.execute("""CREATE TABLE codigo 
       (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, codigo_db real, 
       descripcion_db text, UND_db text, price_db text, cant_db text, cost_db text)""")
    connection_db.commit() # GUARDAR TABLA CREADA
    connection_db.close()

except:

    cont_1=0


class Product: 

    db_name = "kardex.db"

    def __init__(self,window):   
        self.wind = window
        self.wind.title('Kardex')
        window.geometry("784x480")

        my_menu = Menu(self.wind)
        self.wind.config(menu=my_menu)

        my_menu.add_command(label="Salir del registro", command = self.exit)

        frame = LabelFrame(self.wind, text = '\t \t \t \t   Registro      de\tInsumos',fg='navy',font=("Calibri", 12))
        frame.grid(row = 0, column = 4, columnspan = 3, pady = 7, padx= 15)

        Label(frame, text = 'Código', fg = 'black').grid(row = 1, column = 0, pady = 1)
        self.name = Entry(frame)
        self.name.focus()
        self.name.grid(row = 2, column = 0)

        Label(frame, text = "Descripción", fg = 'black').grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        self.name1 = Entry(frame)
        self.name1.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

        Label(frame, text = 'UND', fg = 'black').grid(row = 1, column = 2)
        self.name2 = Entry(frame)
        self.name2.grid(row = 2, column = 2)

        Label(frame, text = 'St.Bodega', fg = 'black').grid(row = 1, column = 3)
        self.price = Entry(frame)
        self.price.grid(row = 2, column = 3)

        Label(frame, text = 'Cantidad.adq', fg = 'black').grid(row = 1, column = 4)
        self.price1 = Entry(frame)
        self.price1.grid(row = 2, column = 4)

        Label(frame, text = "Costo", fg = 'black').grid(row = 1, column = 5 )
        self.price2 = Entry(frame)
        self.price2.grid(row = 2, column = 5)

        ttk.Button(frame, text = 'Guardar datos', command=self.add_product).grid(row = 3, columnspan = 6, sticky = W + E)

        Label(frame, text = 'Buscar registro:',font=("Calibri", 11) ).grid(row = 8, column = 1)
        self.look = Entry(frame)
        self.look.grid(row = 8, column = 2)

        ttk.Button(frame, text = 'Buscar datos', command = self.search).grid(row = 8, column=3, columnspan=1, padx=8, sticky = W + E)
        self.btn_search = ttk.Button(frame, text="Restablecer datos", command = self.reset)
        self.btn_search.grid(row = 8, column = 4,sticky = W + E)

        self.message = Label(frame, text = '', fg = 'red')
        self.message.grid(row = 5, column = 3, columnspan = 2, sticky= W +E) 

        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(frame, height= 12, columns = 4)
        vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(orient="vertical",command=self.tree.yview)
        vsb.place(x=767, y=158, height=242+25)
        self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
        self.tree.grid(row = 6, column = 0, columnspan = 7, pady= 15)
        self.tree['column'] = ('#0', '#1', '#2', '#3', '#4') 
        self.tree.heading('#0', text = 'Código')
        self.tree.column ('#0',width = 100) 
        self.tree.heading('#1', text = 'Descripción')
        self.tree.column ('#1',width = 252)
        self.tree.heading('#2', text = 'UND' )
        self.tree.column ('#2',width = 95)
        self.tree.heading('#3', text = 'St.Bodega')
        self.tree.column ('#3',width = 100)
        self.tree.heading('#4', text = 'Cantidad.adq')
        self.tree.column ('#4',width = 100)
        self.tree.heading('#5', text = 'Costo')
        self.tree.column ('#5',width = 100)

        #llenar filas
        self.get_products()

    def run_query(self, query, parameters = ()): 
        with sqlite3.connect(self.db_name) as conn : 
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            result = cursor.execute(query, parameters)
            conn.commit()
        return result

    def get_products(self):  
        records = self.tree.get_children()
        for element in records:
            self.tree.delete(element)
        query = 'SELECT * FROM codigo ORDER BY ID DESC' 
        db_rows = self.run_query(query) 
        for row in db_rows:
            self.tree.insert('', 0, text = (row[1]), values = (row [2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6]))
 
    def validation(self):
        try:   
            
            return str(self.name.get()), (self.name1.get()), str(self.name2.get()), int(self.price.get()), int(self.price1.get()) and float(self.price2.get())
        
        except ValueError:
        
            mb.showerror('Los datos no se han podido registrar','Los datos no han sido ingresados o han sido ingresados incorrectamente', icon = 'error')

    def add_product(self):
        if self.validation() : 
            query = 'INSERT INTO codigo VALUES(NULL, "{}", "{}", "{}", "{}", "{}", "{}")'.format(self.name.get(), self.name1.get(), self.name2.get(), self.price.get(), self.price1.get(), self.price2.get())
            self.run_query(query)
            self.message['text'] = 'Producto {} añadido exitosamente'. format(self.name1.get())
            self.name.delete  (0,END)
            self.name1.delete (0,END)
            self.name2.delete (0,END)
            self.price.delete (0,END)
            self.price1.delete(0,END)
            self.price2.delete(0,END)
        else:
            self.message['text'] = 'Ingrese los datos/ingreselos correctamente'
        self.get_products()

    def reset(self):
        self.get_products()

    def search(self): 
     
        self.lookup_records = self.look.get() 
        query=' SELECT ID FROM codigo WHERE codigo_db=?'
        parameters = (self.lookup_records,)
        self.lis_tabla=self.run_query(query,parameters).fetchall()
        if len(self.lis_tabla)>0:
            self.message['text'] = 'Registro encontrado '
            self.get_products()
        else:
            self.message['text'] = 'Registro no encontrado '
        
     
    def exit(self):
        MsgBox = mb.askquestion('Salir de la aplicación', '¿Está seguro de que desea salir del registro?', icon='warning')
        if MsgBox == 'yes':
            window.destroy()
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = Tk()
    window.resizable(0,0)
    application = Product(window)
window.mainloop()
```

Los cambios los realice en la función de (add_product) y (search).

```py
    def add_product(self):
        if self.validation() : 
            query = 'INSERT INTO codigo VALUES(NULL, "{}", "{}", "{}", "{}", "{}", "{}")'.format(self.name.get(), self.name1.get(), self.name2.get(), self.price.get(), self.price1.get(), self.price2.get())
            self.run_query(query)
            self.message['text'] = 'Producto {} añadido exitosamente'. format(self.name1.get())
            self.name.delete  (0,END)
            self.name1.delete (0,END)
            self.name2.delete (0,END)
            self.price.delete (0,END)
            self.price1.delete(0,END)
            self.price2.delete(0,END)
        else:
            self.message['text'] = 'Ingrese los datos/ingreselos correctamente'
        self.get_products()

    def search(self): 
     
        self.lookup_records = self.look.get() 
        query=' SELECT ID FROM codigo WHERE codigo_db=?'
        parameters = (self.lookup_records,)
        self.lis_tabla=self.run_query(query,parameters).fetchall()
        if len(self.lis_tabla)>0:
            self.message['text'] = 'Registro encontrado '
            self.get_products()
        else:
            self.message['text'] = 'Registro no encontrado '
```

En el caso de la tabla la configure de esta forma.

```py
tables_connection_db.execute("""CREATE TABLE codigo 
       (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, codigo_db real, 
       descripcion_db text, UND_db text, price_db text, cant_db text, cost_db text)""")
```

Comment: Cuales son las diferencias entre el código del OP y el tuyo? Como este nuevo código soluciona el problema? Podrías explicar eso en tu respuesta por favor?